# Как удалять по одной строке?

Tags: java, javafx

Метод `erase()`, который должен удалять одну верхнюю строчку текста в секунду в поле `textArea` (JavaFX).

Если вставить большой текст, то он выравнивается под размер окна и метод удаляет не строчки, а целые абзацы. Как удалять по одной строке?

```
public void erase() {
    timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), ae -> {
        String text = textArea.getText();
        int position = text.indexOf('\n');
         if (text.length() > 0) {
            textArea.setText(text.substring(position + 1, text.length()));
        }
        else {
            textArea.setText("");
            timeline.stop();
        }
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
}
```

Comment: Получайте текст не из окна textArea.getText(), а храните отдельную переменную с текущим текстом и именно из нее получайте, убирайте строку и кладите в текстовый компонент.

Comment: Передовайте text по одной строке.